# display metabox on front end (my-metabox-class)

Tags: metabox

I would like to display metabox repeater fields on the frontend.

Here is the code to setup the metabox repeater fields:

```
$my_meta =  new AT_Meta_Box($config);  

$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addText($prefix.'t_field_id',array('name'=> 'Title'),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addText($prefix.'d_field_id',array('name'=> 'Description'),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addText($prefix.'p_field_id',array('name'=> 'Price'),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addImage($prefix.'i_field_id',array('name'=> 'Image'),true);
$my_meta->addRepeaterBlock($prefix.'re_',array('inline' => true, 'name' => 'This is a Repeater Block','fields' => $repeater_fields));      
$my_meta->Finish();
```

I tried to use this code:

```
$title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'mt_t_field_id',true); 
                    echo $title;
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see people using my class :)

Anyway when you save a field in a repeater block , to access the data you need to use the repeater ID which in your case it's

```
   $repeater_data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$prefix.'re_',true);
```

and this returns an array of arrays with the id as key and value as value so you can loop over the array like this:

```
foreach($repeater_data as $arr){
   echo 'title: ' . $arr[$prefix.'t_field_id'];
   echo '<br />Description: ' . $arr[$prefix.'d_field_id'];
   echo '<br />Price: ' . $arr[$prefix.'p_field_id'];
   echo '<br />image: <img src="' . $arr[$prefix.'i_field_id']['url']">';
}
```

to understand better how an image field is stored take a look at the [**`class's wiki`**](https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box/wiki/Image-field)
or the comments on [**`this post`**](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox)

Comment: just a little question, why the foreach data return an invalid argument supplied... $repeater_data is an array ?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your code, but you can simply do a `var_dump($repeater_data);` once to see whats going on there.

Comment: ok all is fine i was make a mistake with the $prefix... so noob :) all apologies and thanks again sir

Comment: Glad it worked out for you